# Perguntas mal feitas porém de conteúdo que possa ser útil

Tags: debate

Algumas perguntas são interessantes no contexto geral, como por exemplo [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/289464/importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-arquivo-com-load-data-input). Como editores, podemos sugerir alguma edição para melhorar o conteúdo, porém, não sei até que ponto isso é o certo.

Exemplo:

Poderia reescrever essa mesma questão de forma mais objetiva:

> Em uma aplicação WEB, qual a melhor forma de trafegar um arquivo de 3 milhões de registros?

Digo interessante pois é uma solução que pode beneficiar diversas pessoas, ou seja, ao meu ver é algo importante para a comunidade.

É apenas um exemplo, mas percebo que isso acontece em diversas situações.

O que é mais apropriado fazer?

Comment: Acho que já foi discutido no meta, sobre fechar a ruim e refazer a pergunta de uma maneira melhor ou tentar salvar a original, vale uma pesquisadinha (de qq forma, é uma questão extremamente relevante).

Comment: Independente de ser duplicata ou não, é simples, se acha que consegue melhorar a pergunta e tem disposição pra isso, manda ver. Só cuidado para não deturpar as intenções do autor original.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É simples: o site incentiva que os conteúdos sejam melhorados sempre que possível, por isso todos os usuários podem editar qualquer conteúdo (ou sugerir um edição sujeita à aprovação da comunidade).

Então, se acha que consegue melhorar a pergunta e tem disposição pra isso, manda ver. Só cuidado para não deturpar as intenções do autor original.

Answer (score 7):

Existem "prêmios" por ajudar uma pergunta a ficar melhor. Enquanto você não tiver reputação suficiente para editar publicações por conta própria, cada sugestão de edição que você fizer e for aprovada lhe dá dois pontos de reputação.

Além disso, existem medalhas associadas à quantidade de edições que você faz:

- **Intérprete (bronze):** editou e respondeu 1 pergunta (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas, resposta com pontuação > 0)
- **Aprimorador (prata):** editou e respondeu 50 perguntas (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas, resposta com pontuação > 0)
- **Luminar (ouro):** editou e respondeu 500 perguntas (as 2 ações com intervalo de 12 horas, resposta com pontuação > 0)
- **Editor (bronze):** primeira edição
- **Strunk & White (prata):** editou 80 publicações
- **Copidesque (ouro):** editou 500 posts (sem contar posts próprias ou removidos, e edições de tags)
- **Escavador (bronze):** editou primeira publicação inativa há 6 meses
- **Arqueólogo (prata):** editou 100 posts que estavam inativos por 6 meses.

Eu mesmo estou tentando obter todas essas medalhas. Então edite, edite muito, edite pra caramba para melhoras as publicações do site, pois o SO foi feito para isso :)