# É recomendável reescrever uma pergunta?

Tags: debate, edição

```
from ux.stackexchange.com import my_post
```

Não sei se todas as comunidades do StackExchange possuem um código de conduta padrão ou pelo menos esperado que se diga por todas. Mas o caso que vou descrever aconteceu no site [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

Eu fiz [uma pergunta](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/125096/should-i-show-database-generated-ids-to-the-user) no site do UX, e como a minha pergunta estava muito específica para o meu problema, um usuário a editou de forma que generalizasse e pudesse beneficiar uma quantidade maior de usuários da comunidade. Obviamente eu tinha, e tenho, a possibilidade de reverter as alterações, mas não mudou muito o meu objetivo ao fazer a pergunta (apesar que os casos se diferem muito). Se quiserem ver a versão original, podem olhar as edições passadas (só não prestem atenção no inglês haha).

Acredito eu, que ele só o fez por que julgou a minha pergunta muito focada em código, o que não é o foco daquele Stack.

#### Seria correto fazer o mesmo com algumas publicações do StackOverflow PT?

Pesquisei e achei esta pergunta no Meta: [Perguntas mal feitas porém de conteúdo que possa ser útil](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6945/perguntas-mal-feitas-por%c3%a9m-de-conte%c3%bado-que-possa-ser-%c3%batil).

Mas as respostas não parecem responder exatamente esta minha pergunta. Eu quero saber se é correto fazer uma espécie de remake de uma pergunta.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7203/como-arrumar-uma-pergunta